# Is it possible to calculate the weight distribution on each foot from the centre of mass of a human body?

Tags: classical-mechanics, biophysics

I want to know if it’s at all possible to calculate the weight distribution (i.e the relative load supported by each foot) using just the location of the human body’s centre of mass and the distance of the COM to each foot.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This question should have the biophysics tag

Comment: @TJ Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. We can find the weight distrubution of feet, by equating net torque and net force to 0. However, we need the **horizontal distance between COM and the feet** to find the weight distribution.
We cannot find it if we only have distance between feet and COM unless the distance between the feet is also given(Which is ultimately used to find the same horizontal distance between the COM and feet)
Assuming that the feet are just point sized, we can do the following
[image]

One equation is pretty obvious which is
**N1+N2=mg** (net force is 0)

Another equation is of torque=0, torque is a turning force, here torque is 0 as the human being is not rotating(is in rotational equilibrium)

**Torque= force x perpendicular distance**

perpendicular distance is the horizontal distance between COM and feet.
therefore if the horizontal distance and the total weight is given, the forces exerted by floor on the feet is

**N1 = mgx2/(x1+x2)**

**N2 = mgx1/(x1+x2)**

If the feet are not point sized, then the floor will exert more force on one side of the same foot. You feel this when you lean forward, the force exerted by the ground will be more at toes, less at heels. It will create an additional torque, which will reduce the demand for extra torque required to stay in equilibrium.

Hope the answer helps

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer! This answers my question perfectly